# box3.setFromObject doesn't match object.location

Tags: three.js

I got an object (loaded with the loader, stl), where I'm trying to create a 'snapping' effect when moving it.

I create a `THREE.Box3` from the object to do some detection stuff, but I noticed that my `Box3` doesn't match my object's location `object.location`.

I'm sure I'm messing up worldspace, local space etc etc, so can anyone explain me how I could solve this and what is what?

Code:

```
var box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(activeElement);/
    $("#debug").html(

    "<p>location: <span>" + activeElement.position.x + " - " + activeElement.position.z + "</span></p>" +
    "<p>box - min: <span>" + box.min.x + " - " + box.min.z + "</span></p>" + 
    "<p>box - max: <span>" + box.max.x + " - " + box.max.z + "</span></p>" + 
    "<p>sceneScale: <span>" + sceneScale);
```

So location and box-min don't fit, where they should fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`box3` `min` and `max` are point vectors in 3D space, from the lower left behind to the upper right in front of the bounding box.
See this simple example values with a `BoxGeometry` and the size of `(10,10,10)`:

```
mesh.position { x: 0, y: 5, z: 0 }
box.min { x: -5, y: 0, z: -5 }
box.max { x: 5, y: 10, z: 5 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L0rdzbej/12/

[image]

---

Update: as figured out in Chat, to place an object next to another ones bounding box use this formula (for snapping on one side of the x-axis):

`newPosition.x = otherBox.min.x - ( (activeElement.max.x - activeElement.min.x ) / 2 )`

Comment: Thank you, I understand the problem now. But how to I calculate the values that I want then? If I do ´box.min.x -= activeElement.position.x' it still doesn't match the values.

Comment: Add: Wait, my box.min and box.max values change if I move the object (not scale/rotate, just move). How is this possible then? --

Comment: Its correct that they change, they are **points** in 3D space. I updated my Answer how to get the Bounding Box size because maybe thats what you are trying to calculate.

Comment: I've created a chat room to explain more what I want.