# Handling object going off plane - Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am working on a project of mine that has a `plane` with a `grid` that allows you to just snap on objects.  Where I am stuck is, I can't seem to figure out how to tell if an object overhangs the plane, than don't add it if the user triggers a `click`.

Currently:

```
          event.preventDefault();
          this.mouse.x = ( event.clientX / this.renderer.domElement.width ) * 2 - 1;
          this.mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / this.renderer.domElement.height ) * 2 + 1;

          this.raycaster.setFromCamera( this.mouse, this.camera.cam );

          var intersects = this.raycaster.intersectObjects( this.blocks );

          if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {

              var intersect = intersects[ 0 ];

              if ( this.isShiftDown ) { // see if shift is down to remove

                  if ( intersect.object != this.plane ) {

                      this.scene.remove( intersect.object );

                     this.blocks.splice( this.blocks.indexOf( intersect.object ), 1 );

                  }

              } else if(intersect.object == this.plane ){ // add room to canvas

                  var voxel = new THREE.Mesh( this.room.cubeGeometry.clone(), this.room.cubeMaterial.clone() );
                  voxel.position.copy( intersect.point ).add( intersect.face.normal );
                  voxel.position.divideScalar( 50 ).floor().multiplyScalar( 50 ).addScalar( 25 );
                  this.scene.add( voxel );
                  this.blocks.push( voxel );
                  var domEvents   = new THREEx.DomEvents(this.camera.cam, this.renderer.domElement)
                    console.log(voxel);
                  // DOM events for inside 3d rendering
                    domEvents.addEventListener(voxel, 'mouseover', this.onDocumentMouseOverCube.bind(this),false);
                    domEvents.addEventListener(voxel, 'mouseout', this.onDocumentMouseOutCube.bind(this),false);

              }

              this.render();

          }
```

So what happens here is: first we get our `mouse position` - send it to our `raycaster` to setup.  Than we check to see if we have `intersected any objects`.  Now this is all great except.  If an object is bigger than a single `20x20` slot, it will over hang the plane canvas.  I want to be able to deny the user from placing anything if the object over hangs our plane.  The `plane` object is always at position `this.blocks[0]`  So as you can see in the `else if` we check to see if its on plane.  But I am not accounting for, excess of `object overhang`

Any suggestions on the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Compute the bounding box of your object.

   `var voxel = new THREE.Mesh( this.room.cubeGeometry.clone(), this.room.cubeMaterial.clone() );
   voxel.geometry.computeBoundingBox();`
2. When the user clicks on the plane, move the object there and compare the intersection coordinate (x,z) with the bounding box min and max (x,z) values.
3. If one of the bounding box values is bigger or smaller than the plane, then it overhangs.

This is just an idea, I have not tested this. If you need help with the code, let me know.

Comment: When I create a `BoxGeometry` should I attach a `BoxBoundry?`

Comment: Bounding boxes are already built-in functions, I added code to my answer. See this post to learn about the boxes: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31745694/4977165

Comment: Was perfect - I build my own little handler to utilize the mins and max to accomplish this.  Idea was great.

Comment: Wow thats nice :) If you have come up with a working solution it would be nice to add the basic code to your question so others get a quickstart on this!

Answer (score 1):

As per Falk's request to share my function I created off of his answer.

When dealing with our `volex` on creation the key here is to set a `cube.geometry.computeBoundingBox()` - on every `volex` creation.  Reason be, by default we wont have a min or max bounding size.  Which to be able to grab our `depth and width` of our object this is `crucial`.

We already know that the user is on a `PlaneBufferGeometry` or `plane` in my case.  So we pass our `volex` and `plane` to a custom function called `checkOverlapPlane(volex,plane)`

Now in a jiffy, this function grabs our `plane` and `volex` `max and min` boundaries.  In addition we grab the `volex` position which is crucial to figure out the volex position on the `x and z axis`.  We than convert all of our variables to positive numbers only for the fact that it makes it easy to deal with positive numbers and add our different `x and z`.  After converting our intagers to positive intagers we than get our `total position of the min and max volex z and the volex x`.  Which in turn is compared with our `plane min x z and max x z` to return whether the `volex` is hanging off of our plane.

Here is the code:

```
     checkOverlapPlane: function(voxel,plane) { // THIS IS USED TO TELL US IF WE ARE OUTSIDE THE GRIDS BOUNDRIES
            // Now before doing anything lets check out min and max boundries to see if our x and z are either bigger or smaller
            var planeMX = plane.geometry.boundingBox.max.x;
            var planeMZ = plane.geometry.boundingBox.max.z;
            var planemX = plane.geometry.boundingBox.min.x;
            var planemZ = plane.geometry.boundingBox.min.z;
                //lets get our voxel min and max vars
            var voxelMX = voxel.geometry.boundingBox.max.x;
            var voxelMZ = voxel.geometry.boundingBox.max.z;
            var voxelmX = voxel.geometry.boundingBox.min.x;
            var voxelmZ = voxel.geometry.boundingBox.min.z;
                // we need to get our voxel position ad to do some math to see if voxel min and max do not go beyound our boundries for our plane
            var voxelPX = voxel.position.x;
            var voxelPZ = voxel.position.z;
                // lets do some calucation and condition
                    // first lets turn everything over to positive for some easy calcuation
            voxelPX = Math.abs(voxelPX); // positions on world view
            voxelPZ = Math.abs(voxelPZ);

            voxelmZ = Math.abs(voxelmZ); // min and max values of our voxel
            voxelmX = Math.abs(voxelmX);
            voxelMZ = Math.abs(voxelMZ);
            voxelMX = Math.abs(voxelMX);

            planemZ = Math.abs(planemZ); // min and max values of our plane our voxels are on
            planemX = Math.abs(planemX);
            planeMZ = Math.abs(planeMZ);
            planeMX = Math.abs(planeMX);
                // now lets calucate X and Z to see if total goes over any of our planes min and max X or Y - remember everything is position but so we can add it to see if its above - we will not actually change the direct objects values
            var totalPositionVoxelminZ = (voxelPZ + voxelmZ);
            var totalPositionVoxelminX = (voxelPX + voxelmX);
            var totalPositionVoxelMAXZ = (voxelPZ + voxelMZ);
            var totalPositionVoxelMAXX = (voxelPX + voxelMX);

                // now lets compare
            if(totalPositionVoxelminZ > planemZ)
                return false; // do nothing
            else if(totalPositionVoxelminX > planemX)
                return false; // do nothing
            else if(totalPositionVoxelMAXZ > planeMZ)
                return false; // do nothing
            else if(totalPositionVoxelMAXX > planeMX)
                return false; // do nothing
            else
                return true;
        },
```

Here is the results:

[image]

[image]

Feel free to use and incorporate this in any project!